# Why does my GitHub profile not showing my commits?

Tags: github

The GitHub profile does not show my commits.

I have figured it out and posted my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out out. I need to make sure the Gihub registered email is same as my local config email. so just set

```
git config --global user.email "myemail@xxx.com"
```

That's it.

Details:
https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/